# Macdeployqt going through unrelated / non-existing libraries

Tags: qt, macdeployqt

So I was able to set up a `MyApp.app` bundle using `MACOSX_BUNDLE` using these:   https://github.com/OpenHantek/openhantek/issues/229
https://github.com/euler0/mini-cmake-qt

The current step is running `macdeployqt MyApp.app` to handle all the target libraries and plugins.

However, when I run macdeployqt, it's trying to find some `sql` libraries, and threw errors because there is no sql. The problem is that my project is not using `sql` at all.

The libraries I'm using are `Core Gui Svg Widgets WebView WebEngine WebEngineCore WebEngineWidgets Concurrent Test`

Comment: `Macdeployqt` doesn't really know that your app doesn't use `sql`. By default it tries to deploy Qt plugins one of which is the `sql` one. Simply put, plugins are dynamic libraries which are **not** linked to by the application at build time but which *can* be explicitly opened by the application at runtime. It's impossible for a deployment tool such as `macdeployqt` to know beforehand whether your app uses `sql` or not - it just tries to deploy it as well as other plugins.

Comment: You can pass `-no-plugins` command line parameter to `macdeployqt` to prevent it from deploying plugins entirely. But then you'd have to carefully deploy the plugins your app actually uses by hand. Alternatively, you can just ignore the errors thrown by `macdeployqt`, especially if they are only about that `sql` plugin.

Comment: Also, it might be that some of Qt modules your app actually uses internally makes use of `QtSql` module and that's why `macdeployqt` tries to deploy that plugin. I'm not entirely sure if that's the case but I wouldn't be surprised if that's true for `WebEngine` or `WebEngineCore`, for example.

Comment: @Dmitry yea looks like even though the errors are there the libraries are properly set up. Thanks!